# Making compiled packages using conda build

Tags: conda, conda-build

I'm trying to get some R packages compiled using `conda build` for upload to anaconda.org, but they just end up containing the recipe. I feel like I may be missing an option for conda build or something. For the sake of this example,
say I download the three files for the recipe for r-aer from here: https://github.com/conda/conda-recipes/tree/master/r-packages/r-aer and then run

```
conda build .
```

Everything goes fine and it creates a bz2 file and says:

```
# If you want to upload this package to anaconda.org later, type:
#
# $ anaconda upload /anaconda/conda-bld/linux-64/r-aer-1.2_4-r3.3.2_0.tar.bz2
```

But, if I go to that file and unzip it, it just contains

```
info/paths.json
info/index.json
info/about.json
info/files
info/recipe/bld.bat
info/recipe/build.sh
info/recipe/meta.yaml
info/recipe/meta.yaml.template
```

In contrast to other packages there which have the R library files themselves.

If I go through the steps of uploading it to anaconda.org, then try to install if from there (add the channel, etc), all it does is put the recipe in the `lib` folder.

Also tried using convert, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like when I ran `conda build .` it was installing the (test) library to the first path given by `.libPaths()`, which wasn't the path to the conda build environment. Setting `.libPaths()` to *only* refer to the active environment directory fixed this problem.